# How to use va_list correctly in a sequence of wrapper functions calls?

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I have an ethernet library for microcontroller (keil rl-tcpnet for lpc2478).
Library uses va_list (standard pointer to arg array macro defined in stdarg.h) in debug output function in such a way:

```
void __debug__ (const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args,fmt);
  vprintf (fmt,args);
  va_end (args);
}
```

However vprintf sends data to incorrect stream and I need to redirect debug output of library to correct serial port.
Library has .c cofigure files and I write c++ code so I use wrapper function pointers to call c++ style code from c code. So I rewrite this function:

```
extern void (* printDebugMsg)(const char * fmt, ...);    
void __debug__ (const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  printDebugMsg(fmt, args);
}
```

other cpp file:

```
void printDebugMsgImplementation(const char * fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;

  char buffer[100] = { 0 };

  sprintf(buffer, fmt, args);

  debugUart->write(buffer);
}
void (* printDebugMsg)(const char * fmt, ...) = &printDebugMsgImplementation;
```

The result debug output looks like:

```
TCP: Init 0 Sockets
IP :  Src. IP : 0.0.14.1668436768
ETH:  Dest.MAC: A1E05E10:A0002B44:5F9F:01:5FF8:33
```

The text and some numbers (like 0) seems to be correct but most other ones seems to be wrongly formatted (however it can be internal library problem also).
I tried to rewrite my code using va_list as it is usually made in examples:

```
void __debug__ (const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args,fmt);
  printDebugMsg(fmt, args);
  va_end (args);
}
```

and .cpp file:

```
void printDebugMsgImplementation(const char * fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;

  char buffer[100] = { 0 };

  va_start(args, fmt);
  vsprintf(buffer, fmt, args);
  va_end(args);

  debugUart->write(buffer);
}
```

However the result is definetely worse that it was:

```
TCP: Init -1579131344 Sockets
ARP:  Dest.IP: -1579131400.-1610601474.24805.4
ARP:  Src.MAC: A1E05DF8:A0002BFE:60FF:04:616C:20
```

What I'm doing wrong? And how to deal with va_list in my case of wrapper functions calls?

Comment: Minor point: names with double-underscore are reserved for implementation use, so call your function something else to avoid possible clashes with things in standard headers

Comment: I never use functions with double underscore. It's library function which signature I can't change. Contact Keil. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass `va_list` to a function expecting `...`, unless that function (of course) expects a `va_list` in the variable-arguments part. Your code clearly does not.

You need to explicitly accept a `va_list` argument into `printDebugMsg()`, since that's what you're passing. See for instance [`vprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/vfprintf) which solves this problem for the `printf()` family.

Comment: You are extremely right, thank you! I changed <...> to va_list in my wrapper function and removed va_list start/end using inside it and all now works fine.

Comment: @FominArseniy It happens. :) Thanks. Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it helped you.